# issue with async returns in js from c# class

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am working on a project at work and  I am using CefSharp to connect c# to JS due to a restriction that I am not allowed to use external servers or even a localhost server to host php or other scripting language. The goal I need to reach is I have an async method in c# that works it is reading the csv that i need to accomplish my job, I have debug stepped through the values and its fine. it returns a Task In my js file which called the method to read the local file and return an array of strings to be handled. I get a pending promise, when i used await the pending promise sits there and halts my browser, I have been searching the internet for help and I havent found anything that seems to work. ill post as much of the current code as I can, I need to find a solution for this or atleast some good pointers to get the value from c# to resolve in the js script so that I can move forward.

```
//C# Code::
    public Task<string[]> GetCSV()
    {
        return GetCSVAsync(Encoding.UTF8, pB.GetDefaultPath(PathSelection.AppPathWeb) + "\\MatId\\Includes\\misc\\questions.csv");
    }
    public async Task<string[]> GetCSVAsync(Encoding encoding, string path)
    {
        string[] lines = new string[1];
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, DefaultBufferSize, DefaultOptions))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                {
                    lines = AddLineToLines(lines, line);
                }
            }
        }
        return lines;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This code is opensourced.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="linesinarray">lines array</param>
    /// <param name="linetoadd">line to add to the lines array</param>
    /// <returns>lines array with new value in length</returns>
    private string[] AddLineToLines(string[] linesinarray, string linetoadd)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(linesinarray[0]))
        {
            linesinarray[0] = linetoadd;
            return linesinarray;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] temp = new string[linesinarray.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < linesinarray.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = linesinarray[i];
            }
            temp[temp.Length - 1] = linetoadd;
            return temp;
        }
    }
//JS Code::
//one attempt::
async function getCSVData() {
try {
    var xValue = jsDBConnection.getCSV().then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
}
//Attempt 2::
async function getCSVData() {
try {
    var xValue = await jsDBConnection.getCSV();
    return xValue;
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
}
```

All of these call c# and run through the c# methods However on return the promise is pending statused and value is undefined, and then jquery runs in an infanite loop until either I pause execution or kill the process it never returns any value.

Im new to async programming and I feel that i can get it working but I dont know where I went wrong... I need some help and I am asking fto help me find what I did wrong.

Thank you,
Jesse Fender

Comment: `and then jquery runs in an infanite loop` what jquery? There is no jquery in your snippet. And what infinite loop? Do you really mean an infinite loop, or some code running over and over again, every xyz seconds?

Comment: I have JQuery else where, and the jquery starts immediately after the return statement in the js function it calls (with out my direct knowledge) jquery.event but from there it sits there and repeats the code until I manually stop it. So more probably a bit of code that is running over and over again from there.

Comment: I am shelving this branch of the project until i can spend some time getting better aquainted with Async methods... and promises. I have rolled back to the mixed async and non async methods which strangely seems to work... ill edit the main post, but not til Tuesday.